# How to compare specific columns with unequal length datasets in R?

Tags: r, list, compare

I have two datasets with few identical columns (block, number). One dataset has more number of rows that the other. I want to identify only those rows that differ between the two sets.

```
block <- c(1:10)
number <- c(1:10)
tray <- c(1:10)

df1 <- data.frame(block, number, tray)

block <- c(1:12)
number <- c(1:12)
key <- c(1:12)

df2 <- data.frame(block, number, key)
```

If I use `library(compare)    compare(df1, df2)` It generates all `FALSE`..probably because they differ in one of the three columns. I only want it to compare via block and numebr to get that it differs in block 11, 12 number 11, 12

Comment: Try witih `anti_join` `anti_join(df2, df1)`

Comment: @akrun What if I wanted to directly merge df1 to df2 by block, number, key regardless of unequal length? I know I can't do merge alone.

Comment: Can you please ask as a new question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using `anti_join` from `dplyr`:

```
dplyr::anti_join(df2, df1, by = c("block", "number"))

#   block number key
#1    11     11  11
#2    12     12  12
```